# what is difference between the two sizes in chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[image]

Hello,this capture is from the dev-tools of chrome.

What I want to ask is what is difference between the two sizes? They are all about the file size?

Comment: Can you post the urls to the actual files. It looks like one might be the compressed file size and the other the uncompressed size.

Comment: Sorry but I captured it by myself,so there is no URL

Comment: What is the text of the two different files?

Comment: I am talking about the full url of the js file  the size is being shown for:  eg `cdn.sstatic.net/js/tageteditornew.en.js?v=`